# scrjura file can't be compiled with texlive and MiKTeX in "admin mode"

Tags: koma-script, scrjura

Like the title suggests it is not possible to compile any scrjura file (see MWE below). I tried to compile it using:

- MiKTeX (MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.7029 (1.40.20) (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)) in "**admin mode**" (= "pdflatex --miktex-admin testfile.tex") with all updates installed => **not working**
- texlive (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)) with all updates installed => **not working**
- MiKTeX in "**normal mode**" (dropping the "--miktex-admin" switch) => **works**

Does anyone else have the same experience? Any solution available?
Thank you!

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrjura}

\begin{document}

\begin{contract}

\Clause{title={Test}}

First paragraph. 

Second paragraph.

\end{contract}

\end{document}
```

In the first two cases above I get the following error message:

```
...
! Argument of \arabic has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.14 F
      irst paragraph.
?
```

Comment: This is a known bug of KOMA-Script Version 3.26b in combination with `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>` (see https://komascript.de/release3.26b, German). Reason is the change of `\refstepcounter` in the new LaTeX2e. It seems that your MiKTeX user mode still uses `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`.

Comment: The bug is already fixed in the [current prerelease of KOMA-Script](https://https://komascript.de/node/1801) version 3.27.